# Facebook invite friend request not received

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios7

I am try to invite friends to my app ,i am used Facebook SDK and `FBWebDialogResult` dialog to send request every thing is working fine it should return request send message. the code i am used is

```
NSMutableDictionary* params =   [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:nil];

[FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil message:@"Cariyuk"
 title:@"Cariyuk"
 parameters:params
 handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
       if (error) {
             // Case A: Error launching the dialog or sending request.
             NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
       } else {
                if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                // Case B: User clicked the "x" icon
                NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
       } else {
                NSLog(@"Request Sent.");
       }
 }}];
```

The problem with this is no request is received to receiver account.
Can anyone suggest me what is wrong with this ?

Comment: Is the app sandboxed? Unless your friend is listed as a tester/developer of the app, he wouldn't receive the invite if the app is sandboxed.

Comment: No the app is live, i have also added iPhone app id in it.